# How to unhide an application?

Tags: installation

I hope you can help me. I have installed ubuntu 12.04 using wubi, my issue is i installed iptux using ubuntu software center, it worked fine, i decided that i wanted it to be hidden at start up, so i changed its setting in preferences. i assumed that if i needed to use it i could go to internet menu and select it. But after restarting i found that after i click on iptux under Internet nothing happens, but i click it after that then a small window shows Fatal Error!! Failed to bind the TCP/UDP port(2425)! Address already in use.

I have tried uninstalling using ubuntu software center and reinstalling it but it still had the same problem. I thought it maybe because some files were not uninstalled by USC, so i installed synaptic and uninstalled iptux (complete uninstallation) and then reinstalled it and the same situation occurs. I was hoping someone could inform me how i could unhide iptux.

Comment: Check my solution here <http://askubuntu.com/questions/156995/iptux-always-runs-in-background>

Answer (score 0):

in 12.04 (unity DE), you need to use dconf-editor (included in package dconf-tools) to edit the configration.

```
$ sudo apt-get install dconf-tools

$ dconf-editor
```

go to **desktop > unity > panel** 
the name is **systray-whitelist**

in **Value** ,add *'all',* in front of the lists, turn them to something like:

```
['all', 'JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Wine', 'Update-notifier']
```

after that, close the dconf-editor and run :

```
$ pkill iptux
$ iptux
```

You will see iptux icon showed up in the notify area.

Comment: by the way, in 13.04 (unity DE) people are not able to set the whitelist any more.