# iptux does not start: "Address already in use" error

Tags: 12.04

I installed iptux , when I tried to open the application it shows the error

```
Fatal Error!! Failed to bind the TCP/UDP port(2425)! Address already in use.
```

Please help me with the error

Answer (score 1):

It seems like iptux crashed and could not cleanly close port no 2425 or it may also mean that an instance of iptux is running, so you need to first kill all instances of iptux from the command line(use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to open a terminal) using:

```
killall iptux
```

and also manually close port no 2425 if that did not close this port using:

```
sudo fuser 2425/tcp
```

and then restart iptux

Answer (score 1):

In 12.04 (Unity DE), you need to use `dconf-editor` (included in package dconf-tools) to edit the configration:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
dconf-editor
```

Go to desktop > unity > panel the name is systray-whitelist

In Value, add 'all', in front of the lists, turn them to something like:

```
['all', 'JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Wine', 'Update-notifier']
```

after that, close the dconf-editor and run:

```
pkill iptux
iptux
```

You will see iptux icon showed up in the notify area.

Answer (score 1):

When I checked System Monitor "**g2ipmsg**" was running. I closed it by clicking End Task. After that when i tried opening iptux, it opened successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if iptux runs in background, see the system monitor. If iptux is running, [change the hide value from "true" to "false"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156995/iptux-always-runs-in-background).